ASP.NET Core - How to resolve error in Fluent Validation
I have this code in an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API using Fluent Validation:
public class CreateBranchBulkUploadCommand : IRequest<Response<string>>
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}

public class CreateBranchBulkUploadCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateBranchBulkUploadCommand, Response<string>>
{
    private readonly IBranchRepositoryAsync _branchRepository;
    private readonly ICompanyRepositoryAsync _companyRepository;
    private readonly ILogger<CreateBranchBulkUploadCommandHandler> _logger;

    public CreateBranchBulkUploadCommandHandler(
        IBranchRepositoryAsync branchRepository,
        ICompanyRepositoryAsync companyRepository,
        ILogger<CreateBranchBulkUploadCommandHandler> logger)
    {
        _branchRepository = branchRepository;
        _companyRepository = companyRepository;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<Response<string>> Handle(CreateBranchBulkUploadCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            if (request.File == null || request.File.Length == 0)
                return Response<string>.Failure("Uploaded file is empty.");

            if (!Path.GetExtension(request.File.FileName).Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return Response<string>.Failure("Invalid file format. Only .xlsx files are allowed.");

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await request.File.CopyToAsync(stream, cancellationToken);
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
                {
                    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (worksheet == null)
                        return Response<string>.Failure("The uploaded file does not contain any worksheet.");

                    var branches = new List<CreateBranchCommand>();

                    for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.Rows; row++)
                    {
                        var companyIdString = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Text;
                        Guid? companyId = null;
                        if (Guid.TryParse(companyIdString, out Guid parsedCompanyId))
                            companyId = parsedCompanyId;

                        var branchName = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Text;
                        var branchType = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Text;
                        var branchAddress = worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Text;
                        var description = worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Text;
                        var telephone1 = worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Text;
                        var telephone2 = worksheet.Cells[row, 7].Text;
                        var email = worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Text;

                        var branchCommand = new CreateBranchCommand
                        {
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            CompanyId = companyId,
                            BranchName = branchName,
                            BranchType = branchType,
                            BranchAddress = branchAddress,
                            Description = description,
                            Telephone1 = telephone1,
                            Telephone2 = telephone2,
                            Email = email
                        };

                        branches.Add(branchCommand);
                    }

                    foreach (var branch in branches)
                    {
                        var validationResult = await ValidateBranchAsync(branch, cancellationToken);

                        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
                        {
                            var errorMessages = string.Join(", ", validationResult.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
                            return Response<string>.Failure($"Validation failed for branch with name '{branch.BranchName}': {errorMessages}");
                        }

                        var handler = new CreateBranchCommandHandler(_companyRepository, _branchRepository, _logger);
                        await handler.Handle(branch, cancellationToken);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Response<string>.Success("Branches imported successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error importing branches from Excel.");
            return Response<string>.Failure("An error occurred while importing branches.");
        }
    }

    private async Task<ValidationResult> ValidateBranchAsync(CreateBranchCommand branch, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var validator = new CreateBranchCommandValidator(_companyRepository, _branchRepository);
        return await validator.ValidateAsync(branch, cancellationToken);
    }
}

I get this error:

Error CS1503
Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<Organizations.Branches.Command.UploadBranch.CreateBranchBulkUploadCommandHandler>' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<Organizations.Branches.Command.CreateBranch.CreateBranchCommandHandler>'

It highlights:
_logger

on this line:
var handler = new CreateBranchCommandHandler(_companyRepository, _branchRepository, _logger);


Create another variable with ILogger<CreateBranchCommandHandler> and provide it to CreateBranchCommandHandler parameter.
private readonly ILogger<CreateBranchCommandHandler> _createBranchCommandLogger;

public CreateBranchBulkUploadCommandHandler(
    IBranchRepositoryAsync branchRepository,
    ICompanyRepositoryAsync companyRepository,
    ILogger<CreateBranchBulkUploadCommandHandler> logger,
    ILogger<CreateBranchCommandHandler> createBranchCommandLogger)
{
    ...
    _createBranchCommandLogger = createBranchCommandLogger;
}

var handler = new CreateBranchCommandHandler(_companyRepository, _branchRepository, _createBranchCommandLogger);

